# Rounding errors with PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am having trouble writing to an image with my Mandelbrot program; it is to do with rounding errors with "(maxx-minx)/width" compared to "(maxy-miny)/width" line 31, which leads to a 501 by 500 picture rather than a 500 square picture. 
((width+1) * length) not (width * length).
How can I fix this?

```
from PIL import Image
from cmath import *
from math import sqrt
from numpy import arange

width = 500
height = 500

minx = -0.752 #float(input("Please enter the minimum x value:"))
maxx = -0.748 #float(input("Please enter the maximum x value:"))
miny = 0.098 #float(input("Please enter the minimum y value:"))
maxy = 0.102 #float(input("Please enter the maximum y value:"))

gradient = Image.open("mandelbrot.png")
gradlist = list(gradient.getdata())

def testMandelbrot(x, y):
    z = 0 + 0j
    c = x + (y*1j)
    iter = 0
    while iter <= 69 and sqrt(z.real**2 + z.imag**2) < 4:
        z = (z*z) + c
        iter += 1
    if iter == 70:
        return (0, 0, 0, 255)
    else:
        return gradlist[int((iter - 1) * 140 / 70)]

img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=(255, 255, 255, 255))
image = [testMandelbrot(x, y) for y in arange(miny, maxy, (maxy-miny)/height) for x in arange(minx, maxx, (maxx-minx)/width)] #this line creates the error ((maxx-minx)/width) / (maxx - min) gives (width+1) not width
print(len(image), img.size)
img.putdata(image)
img.save("picture111.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: I have since tested trying to round values forcibly but this makes the rounding errors worse. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`numpy`'s `linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) rather than `arange`. It will return an array of exactly the given number of evenly spaced samples.

See that `linspace(0.098, 0.102, 500, endpoint=False)` is exactly 500 points long. If you want to include the endpoint, you can leave out `endpoint=False` or pass `endpoint=True`.

With `endpoint=False` if you generate another image with the same size height and width but offset by difference between `max_ - min_` the result would be the adjacent tile depending on which it would result in one of the eight.

Your code would then be:

```
Y = linspace(miny, maxy, height, endpoint=False)
X = linspace(minx, maxx, width, endpoint=False)
image = [testMandelbrot(x, y) for y in Y for x in X]
```

I name the arrays because `Y` is reused `len(X)` times and because height and width are small (500), it doesn't cost much and aids readability.